# KeyError at /add_post/

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a feature restricting users to post more than one in one minuate. Then I have met this error, not sure why this isn't working. Can you please take a look at tell me what my fault is?

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self,form):

        if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
            last_submitted = pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.now())
            self.request.session['last_submitted'] = last_submitted
            save_it = True
        else:
            last_submitted = pickle.loads(self.request.session['last_submitted'])
            delta = datetime.datetime.now() - last_submitted
            save_it = (delta.seconds > 60) # assume allow re-submit after 60 seconds

        if save_it:
          self.object = form.save(commit=False)
          # any manual settings go here

          #self.object.category =      Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

          self.object.moderator = self.request.user
          self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
          self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
          self.object.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
        else:
           # consider redirect as usual, if the user just clicked twice by mistake
           return self.form_invalid(form) # or Http error code



Traceback:
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  249.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  215.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "ebagu/main/views.py" in form_valid
  160.         if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in __getitem__
  48.         return self._session[key]

Exception Type: KeyError at /add_post/
Exception Value: 'last_submitted'
```

Comment: From the traceback webpage there are dropdowns to see the variables implied in each one of these traceback lines. That is often useful to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks off:

```
if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
```

`hasattr` takes two arguments and tells you if an object has a specific property name:

```
hasattr(...)
    hasattr(object, name) -> bool

    Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.
    (This is done by calling getattr(object, name) and catching exceptions.)
```

Do you mean to use the following?

```
if 'last_submitted' not in self.request.session:
```

Comment: You are right that `hasattr` lacks the name argument, what makes me wonder: why the `KeyError` is triggered before the `TypeError`? However, this doubt is probably irrelevant for the question...

Comment: yes this is the correct solution, i meant to do that. Thank you but the reason I added this code is to prevent this; when user clicks submit button twice fast before new page gets loaded, then two posts are made. This doesn't fix the issue unfortunately....any advice how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Riaz Thinking about it, intuition tells me that resolve session['index'] comes first...

Comment: @SebasSBM, you have the same problem?

Comment: @winixxee no, but I had tons of similar problems with Django at my job. Even though right now I haven't a Django environment prepared for testing, I'm trying to give my 2 cents on this issue...

Comment: @SebasSBM ah ok, I think I probably need to fix this issue with client-side programming....I'm gonna have to post this issue on Javascript/Jquery section which worries me because I'm not very good at Javascript.....do you know how to fix this issue by any chance?

Comment: @SebasSBM, the `KeyError` is triggered first because of the [order of evaluation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=459269&seqNum=11).

Comment: @winixxee Try searching specifically for answers about double-click submission. Here is a [link](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/doublesubmit/) that might be useful.

Comment: @Riaz good. That means my intuition is still sharp... I better goto sleep some... 6:00AM O__O

Comment: @Riaz Hello, I've tried with the link you gave me but it's keep failing...sorry but do you mind giving me some example how I should do this, this is my html file http://dpaste.com/1QPN874

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell you from the info you posted is that line 160 in your `views.py` is triggering the error:

```
if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
```

Your traceback complains about a KeyError. It is basically telling you that index 'last_submitted' does not exist in `self.request.session`.

This error is triggered basically because your code is trying to retrieve a value from an object that does not exist inside `session`.